Why Freemarker Template is not parsing the xml with namespace
my earlier question answered here
How to separate XML tags in freemarker in body function
But my xml is coming with namespace, But when i am trying to add the namespace in template its not parsing my xml data. Below is my modified template and sample xml and expected output.
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"D": "http://www.test.org/"}>
<#assign DEALS = body[".//D:MESSAGE/.//D:DEALS[following-
sibling::D:DOCUMENT_SETS]/.//D:DEAL"]>
{
loans:[
 <#list DEALS as d>
    {
         ${d["name(./*)"]} : ${d[".//D:AddressLineText"]}
    }
 </#list>       
    ]
}

Sample Xml
<MESSAGE xmlns="http://www.test.org/">
 <DEALS>
  <DEAL>
    <AddressLineText>Addr1</AddressLineText>
   </DEAL>
   <DEAL>
    <AddressLineText>Addr2</AddressLineText>
   </DEAL>
  </DEALS>
 <DOCUMENT_SETS>
  <DEALS>
    <DEAL>
        <LateChargeAmount>110</LateChargeAmount>
    </DEAL>
   </DEALS>
  </DOCUMENT_SETS>
 </MESSAGE>

Expected output
  {
  "loans": [
      {
          AddressLineText : Addr1
       },
        {
     AddressLineText : Addr2
        }
       ]
    }


if your root element actually looks like this:
<MESSAGE xmlns="http://www.test.org/">

or it is part of this namespace: "http://www.test.org/"
I suppose this xpath
.//D:MESSAGE/.//D:DEALS[following-sibling::D:DOCUMENT_SETS]/.//D:DEAL

needs to be
.//D:MESSAGE/D:DEALS[following-sibling::D:DOCUMENT_SETS]/D:DEAL


The elements in the XML you show doesn't belong to the http://www.test.org/ namespace. They don't belong to any namespace. So, just delete all the D: from the queries, and the ns_prefixes={"D": "http://www.test.org/"}, and then it will work.
Because, .//D:MESSAGE means "find me an element, whose local name is MESSAGE, and it belongs to the http://www.test.org/ namespace". There's no such element in that XML, so it finds nothing.

Sorry i missed the namespace in sample xml , i added it.
